# How to grep a specific version number from html?

Tags: html, curl, grep, numbers, version

Let's say i got this code with curl:

```
<div id="pkgdetails" class="box">
    <h2>Paket-Details: waterfox-bin 56.2.4-1</h2>
```

And i just want to grep the version number (56.2.4-1).
How do i archive it?

Answer (score 0):

here i wrote for jquery version.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div id="pkgdetails" class="box">
    <h2>Paket-Details: waterfox-bin 56.2.4-1</h2>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  alert($("#pkgdetails").find('h2').text().split(' ')[2]);
  </script>
```